# pagination - not working

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, pagination

I don't understand why my pagination is not working! It is displaying ok by default, but When click on 'Next' page or some page number nothing happens, not changing page at all. It's like not recognizing pagination.js or pagination_class.php.
I have another part of site where it is working fine, so not sure did I miss something obvious here?
In same folder have 4 files concerning this:`myaccount_betinghistory.php, myaccount_bettinghistory_sub.php, pagination.js, pagination_class.php.`

Here are all the codes of those files to have everything to look in, I hope you will be able to find bug there!

myaccount_bettinghistory.php:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);
include('pagination_class.php');

?>

<script language="JavaScript" src="pagination.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />


<?PHP

//Session start
@session_start();

//Path to root
$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);

//Require Init
$mode = array();
$mode[] = 'nohtml';
require_once $root . "/inc/php/init.php";

{

?>

<?PHP

}

?>

<?
$qry = "
SELECT timelive,bidprice,match_title,selection,winnings_with_startamount,odds,odds*10 AS gainedodds,username,
CASE 
WHEN each_bid_recorded_Part2.result liKE '' AND each_bid_recorded_Part2.status LIKE 'E' THEN 'pending'
WHEN each_bid_recorded_Part2.result liKE '' AND each_bid_recorded_Part2.status NOT LIKE 'E' THEN 'active'
WHEN each_bid_recorded_Part2.result liKE each_bid_recorded_Part2.selection THEN 'WON'
WHEN each_bid_recorded_Part2.result NOT liKE each_bid_recorded_Part2.selection THEN 'LOST'
END AS result
FROM each_bid_recorded_Part2 WHERE each_bid_recorded_Part2.username LIKE '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'

";

$qry .= " ORDER BY timelive DESC";


//for pagination
$starting=0;
$recpage = 4;//number of records per page

$obj = new pagination_class($qry,$starting,$recpage);       
$result = $obj->result;



function getStyleColorForStatus($status) {
  if ($status == 'WON') {
return '#99ff99';
  }
  else if ($status == 'LOST') {
return '#ff9999';
  }
  else if ($status == 'pending') {
return '#e5e5e5';
  }
  else if ($status == 'active') {
return '#ffffcc';
  }
  return '';
}



?>


<div>
  <div class="pageTop"><img src="images/icons/faqicon.png" width="37" height="37" align=absbottom>      Betting History</div>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</div>
  <div>
<p style="font-size:12px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #535252; text-align: left;">Check your bets with you as a last bidder.</p>
</div>
<table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-size:11px; color: #535252;">
        <form name="form1" action="myaccount_bettinghistory.php" method="POST" style="background-color:#f9f9f9; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1); -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1); box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1);">

        <table border="0" align="left" width="500px" padding-left="0px" style="background:#F9F9F9;">



        <tr><TD colspan="0">

        <div id="page_contents">

            <table width="755px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="center" frame="box" rules="none" style="padding-bottom:2px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:3px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1); -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1); box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1); border: 1px solid #cccccc;">
            <tr style="height: 40px;">
<td width="30%" align="center" td class="winheader"><div class="glowtext">Event Start Time</div></td></td>
<td width="10%" align="center" td class="winheader"><div class="glowtext">Bid Cost</div></td></td>  
<td width="35%" align="center" td class="winheader"><div class="glowtext">Market/Event</div></td></td>
<td width="10%" align="center" td class="winheader"><div class="glowtext">Selection</div></td></td>
<td width="10%" align="center" td class="winheader"><div class="glowtext">Winnings</div></td></td>
<td width="5%" align="center" td class="winheader"><div class="glowtext">Odds</div></td></td>
<td width="5%" align="center" td class="winheader"><div class="glowtext">Gained Odds</div></td></td>
<td width="10%" align="center" td class="winheader"><div class="glowtext">Winning Bidder</div></td></td>
<td width="5%" align="center" td class="winheader"><div class="glowtext">Final Result</div></td></td>
            </tr>
            <?if(mysql_num_rows($result)!=0){
                $counter = $starting + 1;
                while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {?>



    <tr class="initial" onMouseOver="this.className='highlight'" onMouseOut="this.className='normal'">



                    <td align="center"><font color="#333"><? echo $data['timelive']; ?></TD>
                    <td align="center">&euro; <? echo $data['bidprice']; ?></TD>        
                    <td align="left"><font color="#0070c0"><? echo $data['match_title']; ?></TD>                
                    <td align="left"><? echo $data['selection']; ?></TD>
                    <td align="center"><font color="green">&euro; <? echo $data['winnings_with_startamount']; ?></TD>
                    <td align="center"><? echo $data['odds']; ?></TD>
                    <td align="center"><? echo $data['gainedodds']; ?></TD>
                    <td align="center"><? echo $data['username']; ?></TD>
                    <td align="center" style="background-color:<?php echo getStyleColorForStatus($data['result']); ?>"><? echo $data['result']; ?></td>
                    </tr>


                <?
                    $counter ++;
                } ?>


                <tr><TD align="center" colspan="10" style="padding-bottom:1px; padding-top:10px; color:#333;"><? echo $obj->anchors; ?></TD></tr>
                <tr><TD align="center" colspan="10" style="padding-bottom:10px; padding-top:5px; color:#333;"><? echo $obj->total; ?></TD></tr>
            <?}else{?>
                <tr><TD align="center" colspan="10" style="padding-bottom:10px padding-top:10px; color:red;">No Data Found</TD></tr>
            <?}?>
            </TD></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        </tr>
        </TD>
    </form>
</table>

<STYLE>

*{ margin-bottom:0; }



#pagination-flickr li{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
float:left;
font-size:10px;
}
#pagination-flickr a{
float:left;
padding:5px 7px;
margin-right:5px;
border:solid 1px #4d7dc5;
text-decoration:none;
background:#FFFFFF;
color:#4d7dc5;
font-size:10px;
}
#pagination-flickr .previous-off,
#pagination-flickr .next-off {
border:solid 1px #DDDDDD;
cursor:default;
background:#FFFFFF;
border:solid 1px #BBBBBB;
color:#BBBBBB;
padding:4px 6px;
margin-right:5px;
font-size:10px;
}
#pagination-flickr .next a,
#pagination-flickr .previous a {
background:#FFFFFF;
border:solid 1px #BBBBBB;
color:#BBBBBB;
font-size:10px;
}
#pagination-flickr .active{
cursor:default;
background:#4d7dc5;
color:#FFFFFF;
padding:4px 6px;
margin-right:5px;
border:solid 1px #4d7dc5;
font-size:10px;
}
#pagination-flickr a:link,
#pagination-flickr a:visited {
padding:4px 6px;
margin-right:5px;
border:solid 1px #4d7dc5;
background:#FFFFFF;
color:#4d7dc5;
font-size:10px;
}
#pagination-flickr a:hover{
padding:4px 6px;
margin-right:5px;
border:solid 1px #4d7dc5;
background:#ffc04a;
color:#000;
font-size:10px;
}


body,table
{

font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
padding-bottom:5px;
empty-cells: show;


}

.glowtext
{
text-shadow: 0 0 20px white;
color:#333;
font-weight:bold;
}


</STYLE>
```

myaccount_bettinghistory_sub.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);
include('pagination_class.php');

?>

<script language="JavaScript" src="pagination.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

<?PHP

//Session start
@session_start();

//Path to root
$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);

//Require Init
$mode = array();
$mode[] = 'nohtml';
require_once $root . "/inc/php/init.php";


{
?>

<?PHP
}

?>


<?
$qry = "
SELECT timelive,bidprice,match_title,selection,winnings_with_startamount,odds,odds*10 AS gainedodds,username,
CASE 
WHEN each_bid_recorded_Part2.result liKE '' AND each_bid_recorded_Part2.status LIKE 'E' THEN 'pending'
WHEN each_bid_recorded_Part2.result liKE '' AND each_bid_recorded_Part2.status NOT LIKE 'E' THEN 'active'
WHEN each_bid_recorded_Part2.result liKE each_bid_recorded_Part2.selection THEN 'WON'
WHEN each_bid_recorded_Part2.result NOT liKE each_bid_recorded_Part2.selection THEN 'LOST'
END AS result
FROM each_bid_recorded_Part2 WHERE each_bid_recorded_Part2.username LIKE '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'

";

$qry .= " ORDER BY timelive DESC";


//for pagination
if(isset($_GET['starting'])&& !isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
$starting=$_GET['starting'];
}else{
$starting=0;
}
$recpage = 4;//number of records per page

$obj = new pagination_class($qry,$starting,$recpage);        
$result = $obj->result;



function getStyleColorForStatus($status) {
  if ($status == 'WON') {
return '#99ff99';
  }
  else if ($status == 'LOST') {
return '#ff9999';
  }
  else if ($status == 'pending') {
return '#e5e5e5';
  }
return '';
}



?>


<div>
  <div class="pageTop"><img src="images/icons/faqicon.png" width="37" height="37" align=absbottom>      Betting History</div>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</div>
  <div>
<p style="font-size:12px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #535252; text-align: left;">Check your bets with you as a last bidder.</p>
  </div>
<table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-size:11px; color: #535252;">
  </div>        
</div>          
        <table border="0" align="left" width="500px" padding-left="0px" style="background:#F9F9F9;">



        <tr><TD colspan="0">

        <div id="page_contents">

            <table width="98%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="center" frame="box" rules="none" style="padding-bottom:2px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:3px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1); -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1); box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1); border: 1px solid #cccccc;">
            <tr style="height: 40px;">
<td width="30%" align="center" td class="winheader"><div class="glowtext">Event Start Time</div></td></td>
<td width="10%" align="center" td class="winheader"><div class="glowtext">Bid Cost</div></td></td>  
<td width="35%" align="center" td class="winheader"><div class="glowtext">Market/Event</div></td></td>
<td width="10%" align="center" td class="winheader"><div class="glowtext">Selection</div></td></td>
<td width="10%" align="center" td class="winheader"><div class="glowtext">Winnings</div></td></td>
<td width="5%" align="center" td class="winheader"><div class="glowtext">Odds</div></td></td>
<td width="5%" align="center" td class="winheader"><div class="glowtext">Gained Odds</div></td></td>
<td width="10%" align="center" td class="winheader"><div class="glowtext">Winning Bidder</div></td></td>
<td width="5%" align="center" td class="winheader"><div class="glowtext">Final Result</div></td></td>
            </tr>
            <?if(mysql_num_rows($result)!=0){
                $counter = $starting + 1;
                while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {?>



    <tr class="initial" onMouseOver="this.className='highlight'" onMouseOut="this.className='normal'">


                    <td align="center"><font color="#333"><? echo $data['timelive']; ?></TD>
                    <td align="center">&euro; <? echo $data['bidprice']; ?></TD>        
                    <td align="left"><font color="#0070c0"><? echo $data['match_title']; ?></TD>                
                    <td align="left"><? echo $data['selection']; ?></TD>
                    <td align="center"><font color="green">&euro; <? echo $data['winnings_with_startamount']; ?></TD>
                    <td align="center"><? echo $data['odds']; ?></TD>
                    <td align="center"><? echo $data['gainedodds']; ?></TD>
                    <td align="center"><? echo $data['username']; ?></TD>
                    <td align="center" style="background-color:<?php echo getStyleColorForStatus($data['result']); ?>"><? echo $data['result']; ?></td>
                    </tr>


                <?
                    $counter ++;
                } ?>


                <tr><TD align="center" colspan="10" style="padding-bottom:1px; padding-top:10px; color:#333;"><? echo $obj->anchors; ?></TD></tr>
                <tr><TD align="center" colspan="10" style="padding-bottom:10px; padding-top:5px; color:#333;"><? echo $obj->total; ?></TD></tr>
            <?}else{?>
                <tr><TD align="center" colspan="10" style="padding-bottom:10px padding-top:10px; color:red;">No Data Found</TD></tr>
            <?}?>
            </TD></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        </tr>
        </TD>

    </table>
```

pagination.js:

```
var xmlHttp

function pagination(page)
{
xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlHttp==null)
  {
  alert ("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
  return;
  }
var url="myaccount_bettinghistory_sub.php";
url = url+"?starting="+page;
url = url+"&search_text="+document.form1.search_text.value;
url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
} 

function stateChanged() 
{ 
if (xmlHttp.readyState==4)
{ 
document.getElementById("page_contents").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
}
}

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
var xmlHttp=null;
try
  {
  // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
  xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
catch (e)
  {
  // Internet Explorer
  try
    {
    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
  catch (e)
    {
    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
  }
return xmlHttp;
}
```

pagination_class.php:

```
<?
/*
Developed by Reneesh T.K
reneeshtk@gmail.com
You can use it with out any worries...It is free for you..It will display the out put like:
First | Previous | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7| 8 | 9 | 10 | Next | Last
Page : 7  Of  10 . Total Records Found: 20
*/
class Pagination_class{
var $result;
var $anchors;
var $total;
function Pagination_class($qry,$starting,$recpage)
{
    $rst        =   mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
    $numrows    =   mysql_num_rows($rst);
    $qry         .= " limit $starting, $recpage";
    $this->result   =   mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
    $next       =   $starting+$recpage;
    $var        =   ((intval($numrows/$recpage))-1)*$recpage;
    $page_showing   =   intval($starting/$recpage)+1;
    $total_page =   ceil($numrows/$recpage);

    if($numrows % $recpage != 0){
        $last = ((intval($numrows/$recpage)))*$recpage;
    }else{
        $last = ((intval($numrows/$recpage))-1)*$recpage;
    }
    $previous = $starting-$recpage;
    $anc = "<ul id='pagination-flickr'>";
    if($previous < 0){
        $anc .= "<li class='previous-off'><<</li>";
        $anc .= "<li class='previous-off'><</li>";
    }else{
        $anc .= "<li class='next'><a href='javascript:pagination(0);'><< </a></li>";
        $anc .= "<li class='next'><a href='javascript:pagination($previous);'>< </a></li>";
    }

    ################If you dont want the numbers just comment this block############### 
    $norepeat = 4;//no of pages showing in the left and right side of the current page in the anchors 
    $j = 1;
    $anch = "";
    for($i=$page_showing; $i>1; $i--){
        $fpreviousPage = $i-1;
        $page = ceil($fpreviousPage*$recpage)-$recpage;
        $anch = "<li><a href='javascript:pagination($page);'>$fpreviousPage </a></li>".$anch;
        if($j == $norepeat) break;
        $j++;
    }
    $anc .= $anch;
    $anc .= "<li class='active'>".$page_showing."</li>";
    $j = 1;
    for($i=$page_showing; $i<$total_page; $i++){
        $fnextPage = $i+1;
        $page = ceil($fnextPage*$recpage)-$recpage;
        $anc .= "<li><a href='javascript:pagination($page);'>$fnextPage</a></li>";
        if($j==$norepeat) break;
        $j++;
    }
    ############################################################
    if($next >= $numrows){
        $anc .= "<li class='previous-off'>></li>";
        $anc .= "<li class='previous-off'>>></li>";
    }else{
        $anc .= "<li class='next'><a href='javascript:pagination($next);'>> </a></li>";
        $anc .= "<li class='next'><a href='javascript:pagination($last);'>>></a></li>";
    }
        $anc .= "</ul>";
    $this->anchors = $anc;

    $this->total = "Page : $page_showing of $total_page  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Total Records Found: $numrows";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Is there anything in your web server error log and/or your JavaScript console?

Comment: uh, I'm sorry, sounds silly but I am actually not that much experienced so don't know how to check that at the moment :(

Comment: You should stop everything you're trying to do and figure out those two things:  (1) where your web server logs are and how to read them and (2) how to view your JavaScript console.

Answer (score 0):

remove this

```
&& !isset($_REQUEST['submit'])
```

you are not using it !!!

Comment: Removed it, but not helping, still pagination not functioning.

Comment: try using firebug in firefox to see what javascript is sending and what type of respons do you get. and try to run the script directly

Comment: I tryed in Google Chrome 'Inspect Element' and receiving this error there: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined     
pagination
(anonymous function)`